# JavaDB Shows Errors and doesn't start

Tags: java, netbeans, javadb

After spending a few hours through Google and StackOverflow, i am here to ask you a question about this error:

```
Fri Jan 17 10:54:17 IST 2014 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
Fri Jan 17 10:54:17 IST 2014 : access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1527" "listen,resolve")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1527" "listen,resolve")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkListen(SecurityManager.java:1134)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at javax.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(ServerSocketFactory.java:231)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.createServerSocket(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.blockingStart(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.executeWork(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl.main(Unknown Source)
```

I get this when I try to start up my JavaDB. It doesn't work at all, I tried almost everything in the internet, your kind help will be highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I fixed this problem by going to this link: http://hanynowsky.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/oracle-sun-jdk-7-derby-server-java-db-does-not-start-using-glassfish-3-1-2-in-netbeans-7-1-2-permission-denied/ and editting my java.policy file! Thank you everyone if you tried to help!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by editting my Java.policy file at http://hanynowsky.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/oracle-sun-jdk-7-derby-server-java-db-does-not-start-using-glassfish-3-1-2-in-netbeans-7-1-2-permission-denied/

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, but just fixing the listen port might not be enough to do the charm.

When you look at the derby documentation, say:
http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/adminguide/tadminnetservbasic.html

You see that there is quite a set of significant permissions. Not just being able to open a port.
Writing to files, reading files etc..

So, JRE 7 is way more restrictive than JRE 6. 
There is no guarantee that your pain will end by puting like a hammer in java policy a simple allow to open socket on listen port.

My recommentation would be to:

(a) Tune your policy file. With derby template policy

(b) Tune your startup datbase command to defne the required policy referenced properties

For example, if you are ussing glassfish:
asadmin start-database --jvmoptions="-Dderby.install.url=%DERBY_INSTALL_URL% -Dderby.system.home=%DERBY_SYSTEM_HOME%"

Where DERBY_INSTALL_URL is string of rh form: `file:/c/mypath/to/a/derby/intallFolder/lib/`

```
    // ///////////////////////////////////////////
    // COPY PASTED PERMISSIONS FROM THE NET - MAKE SURE THE START DERBY COMMAND DEFINEDS THE ${derby.install.url}
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////


    // REFERENCES:
    // http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/adminguide/tadminnetservbasic.html
    // http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/adminguide/
    // This template policy file gives examples of how to configure the
    // permissions needed to run a Derby network server with the Java
    // Security manager.
    //
    grant codeBase "${derby.install.url}derby.jar" {
        //
        // These permissions are needed for everyday, embedded Derby usage.
        //
      permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "createClassLoader";
      permission java.util.PropertyPermission "derby.*", "read";
      permission java.util.PropertyPermission "user.dir", "read";
      permission java.util.PropertyPermission "derby.storage.jvmInstanceId", 
          "write"; 
      // The next two properties are used to determine if the VM is 32 or 64
      // bit.
      permission java.util.PropertyPermission "sun.arch.data.model", "read";
      permission java.util.PropertyPermission "os.arch", "read";
      permission java.io.FilePermission "${derby.system.home}","read";
      permission java.io.FilePermission "${derby.system.home}${/}-", 
          "read,write,delete";

        //
        // This permission lets a DBA reload the policy file while the server
        // is still running. The policy file is reloaded by invoking the
        // SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_RELOAD_SECURITY_POLICY() system procedure.
        //
          permission java.security.SecurityPermission "getPolicy";

        //
        // This permission lets you backup and restore databases
        // to and from arbitrary locations in your file system.
        //
        // This permission also lets you import/export data to and from
        // arbitrary locations in your file system.
        //
        // You may want to restrict this access to specific directories.
        //
          permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>",
              "read,write,delete";


        //
        // Permissions needed for JMX based management and monitoring, which is
        // only available for JVMs supporting "platform management", that is
        // Java SE 5.0 or better.
        //
        // Allows this code to create an MBeanServer:
        //
          permission javax.management.MBeanServerPermission "createMBeanServer";
        //
        // Allows access to Derby's built-in MBeans, within the domain
        // org.apache.derby.
        // Derby must be allowed to register and unregister these MBeans.
        // It is possible to allow access only to specific MBeans, attributes or 
        // operations. To fine tune this permission, see the javadoc of 
        // javax.management.MBeanPermission or the JMX Instrumentation and Agent 
        // Specification. 
        //
          permission javax.management.MBeanPermission 
              "org.apache.derby.*#[org.apache.derby:*]",
              "registerMBean,unregisterMBean";
        //
        // Trusts Derby code to be a source of MBeans and to register these in
        // the MBean server.
        //
          permission javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission "register";

          // getProtectionDomain is an optional permission needed for printing
          // classpath information to derby.log
          permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getProtectionDomain";

          //
          // The following permission must be granted for
          // Connection.abort(Executor) to work. Note that this permission
          // must also be granted to outer (application) code domains.
          //
          permission java.sql.SQLPermission "callAbort";
};


    // grant codeBase "${derby.install.url}derbynet.jar"{
    // grant codeBase "file:/D:/cranebox-package/package/cranebox/glassfish-v3/javadb/lib/derbynet.jar" {
    grant codeBase "${derby.install.url}derbynet.jar"{
        permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:1527", "listen";

    //
    // This permission lets the Network Server manage connections from
    // clients.
    //

    // Accept connections from any host. Derby is listening to the host
    // interface specified via the -h option to "NetworkServerControl
    // start" on the command line, via the address parameter to the
    // org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl constructor in the API
    // or via the property derby.drda.host; the default is localhost.
    // You may want to restrict allowed hosts, e.g. to hosts in a specific
    // subdomain, e.g. "*.example.com".

      permission java.net.SocketPermission "*", "accept"; 

    //
    // Needed for server tracing.
    //
      permission java.io.FilePermission "${derby.drda.traceDirectory}${/}-",
          "read,write,delete";

    //
    // JMX: Uncomment this permission to allow the ping operation of the 
    //      NetworkServerMBean to connect to the Network Server.
    //permission java.net.SocketPermission "*", "connect,resolve";


    //
    // Needed by sysinfo. The file permission is needed to
    // check the existence of jars on the classpath. You can
    // limit this permission to just the locations which hold
    // your jar files.
    //
    // In this template file, this block of permissions is granted
    // to derbynet.jar under the assumption that derbynet.jar is
    // the first jar file in your classpath which contains the
    // sysinfo classes. If that is not the case, then you will want
    // to grant this block of permissions to the first jar file
    // in your classpath which contains the sysinfo classes.
    // Those classes are bundled into the following Derby
    // jar files:
    //
    //    derbynet.jar
    //    derby.jar
    //    derbyclient.jar
    //    derbytools.jar
    //
      permission java.util.PropertyPermission "user.*", "read";
      permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.home", "read";
      permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.class.path", "read";
      permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.runtime.version", "read";
      permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.fullversion", "read";
      permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getProtectionDomain";
      permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "read";
      permission java.io.FilePermission "java.runtime.version", "read";
      permission java.io.FilePermission "java.fullversion", "read";
    };
```

(c) If you are desperate, and just want the DB up and running quick and you just do not care about security. Just put this hammer in your security policy for the JRE:

`permission java.security.AllPermission "", "";`